# Why no 3200x1800 resolution on an M2 MacBook Air on a 5K display?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution, 5k

My preferred resolution is 3200x1800 on a 27" display. For some reason, the new M2 MacBook Air does not offer this resolution, neither on an LG Ultrafine 5K, nor the Apple Studio Display.

Using an iMac Pro or a MacBook Pro, with either display, gives the 3200x1800 option.

This is true with both Monterey and Ventura. The "Show all resolutions" switch does not help.

I called a senior advisor at Apple and he was stumped.

Is this a hardware limitation of the Air's GPU? Is there any way to get 3200x1800?

MacBook Pro:
[image: ![LG on MacBook Pro]

iMac Pro:
[image]

MacBook Air:
[image]

MacBook Air:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try https://www.madrau.com/

Answer (score 1):

Solved, using https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution

Available via `brew install screenresolution`

`screenresolution set 3200x1800x32@60` works on MacBook Air, FTW!